# Using column names of data.frame

Tags: r, anova

I have the following (simplified) text file, which is named `datafile.txt`:

```
Height Color Sales     
short blue 24    
short blue 25   
short red 31   
short red 28   
short black 35   
short black 32   
tall blue 31   
tall blue 32   
tall red 36   
tall red 32   
tall black 41   
tall black 36
```

From this text file, I create the data.frame `data`:

```
data <- read.table("datafile.txt", header = TRUE)
```

By the following line, I can perform a two-way *ANOVA*:

```
anova(lm(Sales ~ Height*Color, data))
```

However, the following code, which I expected to perform a two-way *ANOVA*, does not work:

```
columnNames <- names(data)    
anova(lm(columnNames[3] ~ columnNames[1]*columnNames[2], data))
```

I would like to perform the analysis by using the column names extracted from the data.frame, not by directly typing `Sales`, `Height` and `Color`.  I will very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Despite the use of the word "table", the term `data.table` in R does not refer to the object type created by `read.table`. Dataframes were created first (as part of S and then later in its clone R, but data.tables are an even more recent invention fo Matt Dowle and are quite different. The `read.table` function (and all of its read.* cousins) creates a dataframe. If you did want a data.table, you would need to read that packages documentation and use `fread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `paste` and convert to `formula`

```
anova(lm(formula(paste(columnNames[3], "~",  columnNames[1], "*", columnNames[2])), data))
```

Or even explicit `formula` is not needed

```
anova(lm(paste(columnNames[3], "~",  columnNames[1], "*", columnNames[2]), data))
#Analysis of Variance Table

#Response: Sales
#             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
#Height        1  90.75  90.750 17.8525 0.005529 **
#Color         2 128.17  64.083 12.6066 0.007103 **
#Height:Color  2   3.50   1.750  0.3443 0.721876   
#Residuals     6  30.50   5.083                    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: OR   `anova(lm(get(columnNames[3]) ~ get(columnNames[1])*get(columnNames[2]), data))`

Comment: akrun, G5W, thank you very much for your remarkably prompt and helpful answers.  This is my very first post, and I am just astonished by the effectiveness of this system.